# Strong duality optimal control

Tags: duality-theorems, optimal-control

I'm reading a paper on optimal control, where they prove strong duality, however its form is puzzling to me.

Let $\pi$,$\delta$ be the optimal value of the primal/dual. 
The paper claims that weak duality implies

$-\delta \leq \pi$

Then goes on to show $-\delta = \pi$ and therefore strong duality holds.

I know it's vague, since you don't know the whole context, but has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: weak duality is this inequality by definition. It is a very common notion in optimization, the simplest case being linear prorgamming. Maybe the wiki page on duality gap is helpful

Comment: but weak duality is that $\delta \leq \pi$

Comment: that depends on the meaning of $\delta$ and $\pi$. Maybe they changed max and min somewhere, but there are other ways that could make this plausible